# Shorthand notation for multi-valued variables

Tags: soft-question, notation

Is there a useful shorthand notation for multi-valued variables, e.g. for
$$\large e^{i(2n+\frac 12 )\pi}\qquad \small (n=0,1,2)
$$
would it be acceptable to write this as
$$\large e^{i\frac {\lbrace1,5,9\rbrace}2\pi}
$$
or other similar notation?

Comment: Well it depends where you want to use it.  The first one is the generally accepted one. I haven't seen anyone use the second notation. If you wish to use the second one(when communicating maths etc), make sure you state clearly what it means(also "acceptability" is relative. Unlike other subjects, notations in mathematics is not standardized). Further, I think the second definition will probably make things harder especially during complex calculations.  So it's really up to you!

Comment: @PankajTiwari Thanks for your input. I came up with it while trying to solve  $(z+i)^3=8i$ and wanted to replace $i$ on RHS with the term shown in the question.

Comment: It is likely that the notation $\mathrm{e}^{i\frac{\{1,5,9\}}{2}\pi}$ will be understood.  That being said, I don't think that it is terribly standard, and I personally think that it is rather ugly.  That last bit is, however, entirely a matter of taste.